# Delay anchor link destination till animation completes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css

I am trying to make a page transition occurs with vanilla JS and CSS. I have a class that I wish to add to my element when the 'collection' button is clicked. I have a function where I delay the link redirection by using prevent default, adding a CSS animated class, and then setting a new window location after a delay of 4 seconds. However currently when I click on collections, nothing happens, although when I hover over the text, the link preview is correct. I'm using animate.css's built-in animation which just requires you to link its stylesheet in the head tag and add the animation class to the element.

HTML -

```
<div id="homeContainer" class="home-container">
         <div class="bg-home bg-move">
            <img src="/Home/Asset 3.png" alt="film">
         </div>
         <div class="nav-button-h text-fade">
            <p id="pressbtn">ABOUT</p>
            <p id="logo-center">SHEK LEUNG</p>
            <p id="aboutbtn">PRESS</p>
         </div>
         <div class="nav-button-v text-fade">
            <a href="/collections/MA/MA.html" class="text-fade" id="colbtn">COLLECTIONS</a>
            <p id="projbtn">PROJECTS</p>
         </div>
     </div>
```

JS

```
const colbtn = document.getElementById('colbtn');
const homeContainer = document.getElementById('homeContainer');

colbtn.addEventListener('click', animateDown);

function animateDown(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   homeContainer.classList.add('animate__animated animate__fadeOutDown');
   if (this.href) {
      var target = this.href;
   }
   setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.replace(target);
   }, 4000);

}
```

Comment: are there any errors in the console? Does it find the element? Do you see the class being set on the element when you inspect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add classes like that, they need to be comma separated.

```js
const colbtn = document.getElementById('colbtn');
const homeContainer = document.getElementById('homeContainer');

colbtn.addEventListener('click', animateDown);

function animateDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  homeContainer.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeOutDown');
  if (this.href) {
    var target = this.href;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace(target);
  }, 4000);

}
```

```html
<div id="homeContainer" class="home-container">
  <div class="bg-home bg-move">
    <img src="/Home/Asset 3.png" alt="film">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-button-h text-fade">
    <p id="pressbtn">ABOUT</p>
    <p id="logo-center">SHEK LEUNG</p>
    <p id="aboutbtn">PRESS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-button-v text-fade">
    <a href="/collections/MA/MA.html" class="text-fade" id="colbtn">COLLECTIONS</a>
    <p id="projbtn">PROJECTS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I corrected it to just adding animate__fadeOutDown". Now the link does redirect with a delay but animation doesn't occour

Comment: Did you add both classes like this ('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeOutDown')?